# Import Jenkins Shared Libaray Function Into Python Script

Tags: python, function, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to import a function from a Jenkins shared library into a python script that's also running as part of a Jenkins pipeline?

I have a function in a Jenkins shared libary stored under `/vars`.

`DemoHello.groovy`

```
def call(){
    sh '''
    echo "Hello World"
    '''
}
```

I'm able to call this directly from any pipeline stage. But I would like to import it into a python script.

`DemoImport.groovy`

```
def call() {
sh '''
cat <<EOF > main.py
import DemoHello

result = 200

if result == 200:
   DemoHello()
else:
   print("Result is not 200")
EOF
'''

sh '''
python main.py
'''
}
```

And then in my Jenkinsfile:

```
stages {
    stage ('Echo Hello') {
        steps {
            DemoImport()
        }
    }
```

I would expect this to echo Hello World but it doesn't do anything.

No errors, nothing. It just bypasses it completely.

Is there a way to import functions from shared libraries into a python script?

Comment: Python would be unable to directly invoke Groovy like this, so no. You would need some cross-language API such as REST or gRPC.

Comment: Furthermore, Python runs on the agent, whereas the pipeline script runs on the controller. If your task really amounts to running some shell script, you can of course do that from Python directly using `subprocess.run()` and friends, but this does not expose anything from your Jenkinsfile to Python. Saving the shell script as an external file and committing it to your version control system would make it available to everything in the pipeline, though.